# What do we do if we've been deliberately downvoted for no reason?

Tags: discussion

I just noticed the following entries in my rep:
[image]

It looks like someone disliked something I said somewhere along the line and decided to downvote some of my top ranking answers.

Is there a way to determine who did this or reverse the action? I dare say that no-one read all the answers in under two minutes and then decided they were all without merit.

Answer (score 4):

Usually serial down-voting is automatically reversed. It's interesting that some votes from that day were already reversed. I'll have to ask staff, though, since I can't find out detail from individual votes.

Comment: Yeah I thought it was, so I'm confused as well. Does the user who did it get warned?

Comment: This seems to be the canonical meta.so post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/154443

Comment: Yea I've had this once I just contacted a mod and they fixed it.